# C++ function returning const char *

Tags: c++, string, pointers, malloc, constants

I've developed a small helper function for a unit test class, which takes my `vector<unsigned char>` and converts it back to a `const char *`. I wrote this so I can pass it to gtest's `ASSERT_STREQ` macro for simple comparisons. Here it is:

```
const char * convertVecToChar(std::vector<unsigned char>& source)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char>::size_type size = source.size();
    char* data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1)); 
    memcpy(data, &source[0], size);
    data[size] = 0;
    return data;
}
```

And here's an example of it being called:

```
ASSERT_STREQ("de", convertVecToChar(somevector));
```

I presume this is leaky however as I'm calling `malloc`, but without calling `delete` further down the road?

Is there a more elegant way to do this, which does not involve creating a separate `const char *` variable for every time I call `ASSERT_STREQ` within a test method?

Big thanks in advance for all responses.

Chris

Comment: Use `free()` after `malloc()`, not `delete`.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. I don't really have an answer, though. This seems like a giant hack just for unit testing. Did you consider creating a `ASSERT_VECEQ`? Also, maybe you shouldn't care too much for memory leaks in unit tests.

Comment: @DarenThomas - the unit testing library is provided by Google - GTest. Will check if it has such a macro. I prefer to use C Strings as they are easier to read in the tests, however.

Comment: Besides using `std::string` as suggested in an answer, maybe you could use smart pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)? But then you have to use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Return a `std::string` instead of a `char*` (`malloc()`, or `new`, unrequired):

```
std::string convertVecToChar(std::vector<unsigned char>& source)
{
    return std::string(source.begin(), source.end());
}
```

and use:

```
ASSERT_STREQ("de", convertVecToChar(somevector).c_str());
```

Comment: This does seem to be the common-sense approach :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Overload `operator==`, then you can just use ASSERT_EQ:

```
bool operator==(const char* nullTerminatedChars,
                const std::vector<char>& vecChars)
{
    return std::string(nullTerminatedChars) ==
           std::string(vecChars.begin(), vecChars.end());
}
```

Use as:

```
std::vector<char> chars;
ASSERT_EQ("de", chars);
```

You'll need to overload `operator<<(std::ostream& ...` too, as GoogleTest uses it to convert arguments to the assert into error messages if the assertion fails.

edit:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<char>& chars)
{
    return os << std::string(chars.begin(), chars.end());
}
```

Comment: I like this - looks very elegant. But going to need some homework on how to implement the overload properly! (Still a bit of a n00b at this stuff). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) container - no need to worry about memory leaks.

BTW - As you are using C++ - just stick to `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

```
source.push_back(0);
ASSERT_STREQ("de", (char*)&source[0]);
source.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to recommend using std::string too , but I was wondering, why not just compare the contents of the vector? You can access the raw data through `&source[0]`, so you could do:

```
ASSERT_STREQ("de", (char*)&source[0]);
```

Comment: Tried this, but the test failed - `ASSERT_STREQ("de", (const char*)&ret[0]);` - think it's because there's no byte 0 at the end of the vector.

Comment: @MrChris:Yes, I had not thought of that